# Asynchronous vs. Synchronous Encryption Key and is SSL required for my app?

Tags: security, ssl, cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I'd like to secure the payload of a (local-notwork) TCP connection against attackers who snoop    traffic. This payload only gets send in the direction from the client to the server. 
As my application is not sensitive to client authenticity nor data integrity, i don't need signing/ceritificates. 
Therefore the only feature of SSL i need would be its encryption/decryption aka confidentiality.

So i am wondering if a standalone encryption module was sufficient for me. While browsing SO, i frequently stumbled upon warnings about inventing its own security methods.
But now it interests me.

1. So, does a separate shared-key encryption algorithm give me the same protection as SSL, since i'm only interested in making the payload unreadable/unusable for an attacker. (Assert: i'm using the same encryption algorithm that SSL does)
2. And if so, does a (salted/IV) symmetric key encryption?
3. Is there an advantage to an asymmetric encryption, besides the fact, that the user does not need to remember a passprahse as he would need with a symmetric one?

**EDIT:** Just noted, that SSL uses a symmetric algorithm for the encryption part.

Answer (score 1):

Just use SSL.

It was designed for exactly this purpose (to secure communications between a client an a server). Why do you want to re-invent the wheel to try to avoid using it?

This is a relevant post that you should really read: [You are dangerously bad at cryptography](http://happybearsoftware.com/you-are-dangerously-bad-at-cryptography.html)...

Comment: Nice article, thanks!:) First off i generally like to reinvent things to   reenact the mind steps, the original inventor took. Secondly, in my case i'll definitely add a symmetric encryption key on top of SSL, as my remote socket can be accessed by individuals, that i don't want to read the message. So i wondered if this extra layer of encryption would actually be sufficient on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely agree with ircmaxell, you need to have SSL certificate installed on your website.

Now it is depending upon your requirement, which ssl certificate you should buy ! If you are looking for basic SSL product, you should check rapidssl which starts from $8/year.

If you are looking to secure multiple domains or looking for extended validations; there are different SSL available in market for these purposes.

Comment: Thanks. It's not about a website but the communication between a smartphone and a computer. I'm going to use self-signed certificates for that.